# Multiple IF Statements in Power BI query for ISFILTERED

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, switch-statement, dax

I am trying to hide values on a table unless at least one of three slicers is selected.I have scoured the web and it does not seem like any solution is working for me as when I put the measure onto the table, the values do not get hidden.

```
Hide Visual = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISFILTERED(Fips[City Name]),1,
    ISFILTERED(Fips[State Name]),1,
    ISFILTERED(Fips[Zip Code]),1,
    0
)
```

Things I have tried that did not work

```
Hide Visual = IF(
            ISFILTERED(Fips[City Name]) 
            || ISFILTERED(Fips[State Name])
            || ISFILTERED(Fips[Zip Code])
            ,1,BLANK())
```

```
Hide Visual = IF(ISFILTERED(Fips[City Name]),1,
            IF(ISFILTERED(Fips[State Name]),1,
            IF(ISFILTERED(Fips[Zip Code],1,0))))
```

Comment: Have you looked into using query parameters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is ISFILTERED will return true as it has row context.
Try the following:

```
Hide Visual = SWITCH(TRUE(),
  CALCULATE(ISFILTERED(Fips[City Name]), ALLSELECTED(Fips[City Name])), 1,
  CALCULATE(ISFILTERED(Fips[State Name]), ALLSELECTED(Fips[State Name])), 1,
  CALCULATE(ISFILTERED(Fips[Zip Name]), ALLSELECTED(Fips[Zip Name])), 1
)
```